# WPF VS2013: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, dictionary, resourcedictionary

Team,

I have a simple wpf project in Visual Studio 2013. The structure is shown below. All that the error says is as shown in the title "An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary". I have tried many suggestions from the net and running out of patience. Every thing seems to be alright. Any one experienced with this can kindly suggest some thing. Thanks in advance.

[image: VS 2013 Wpf Project Showing the error with respect to resources]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should read:

```
...Source="/Skins/MainSkin.xaml"
```

As the skin isn't in the `Content` directory.

At the moment it's looking for `Content/Skins/MainSkin.xaml` (hence `/` will 'take it up' a directory back to the root).

Comment: Wouldn't it also need .. before the /? Or can he use ~?

Comment: EDIT: Apparently not, (I reverted the edit, see other answer).